# Residue Theorem for Denominator with $e^z$

Tags: residue-calculus

$$ f(z)=\frac{z^3}{e^z-1} $$

- Is this a simple pole at $z=0$ or some other types of pole?

  - If it is a simple pole, what is its residue?
- Is it using this formula or other else?
  $$ \lim_{z\to 0}=zf(z) $$

Comment: What is the order of the zero of $e^z-1$ in $0$?

Comment: so it is a simple pole at z=0?

Comment: Not so fast. How does the numerator, $z^3$ behave in $0$?

Comment: both z^3 and e^z-1 be zero when z=0

Comment: And what happens then? How do you determine whether it's a pole or a removable singularity?

Comment: It is not removable
but I am not sure is this a simple pole or essential...

Comment: Why do you think it's not removable?

Comment: It seems that I have messed up my concept..
why it is removable?

Comment: Write $e^z - 1 = (z-0)\cdot g(z)$, where $g$ is holomorphic with $g(0) \neq 0$. Then $$f(z) = \frac{z^3}{e^z-1} = \frac{z^3}{z\cdot g(z)} = \frac{z^2}{g(z)},$$ and that shows that $f$ not only has a removable singularity in $0$, it even has a zero of order $2$ (which is $3 - 1$) in $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^z=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\implies\frac{z^3}{e^z-1}=\frac{z^3}{z+\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^3}6+\mathcal O(z^4)}=$$

$$=\frac{z^2}{1+\frac z2+\frac{z^2}6+\mathcal O(z^3)}$$

The above shows at once that $\;z=0\;$ is a removable singularity...though the last step requires a little justification (factor out $\;z\;$, and then you can cancel. Why?)